# Will background image affect site loading speed

Tags: html, css, background, stylesheet

On my index page, I have a background image which is added to the div dynamically by some javascript.The inline style added is the following.

```
element.style {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)    
url("http://www.myshop.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/media/bg-footer.jpg") 
no-repeat scroll 50% -287.5px;
}
```

I have changed that background image using the following class

```
.footer-bg{
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 
url("http://www.myshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/blue-living-room.jpg") 
no-repeat scroll 50% -59.5px !important;
margin-top: 20px;
}
```

I have used `!important` for overriding the background style loaded by the javascript and it worked.After changing this site is bit slower than earlier.My doubt here is that Will the site load both style or will it completely ignore the first one?

If the site loads both styles and apply the one with `!important` then it needs some loading time right?

Do these style overriding directly affects site loading speed.Please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If that background add on the same class (`.footer-bg`) then you can override with below method-

```
.footer-bg [style]{
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("http://www.myshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/blue-living-room.jpg") !important;
}
```

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have already changed the image.I haven't removed the inline style just overridden using `!important`.I would like to know whether this will affect site loading speed or not.Actually two different images are loaded using above styles.If the site loads both styles and apply the one with important then it will definitely take some loading time right?